# How to use custom/different colored markers using Mapquest API?

Tags: java, android, mapquest, mapbox-marker, mapbox-android

I am trying to use different colored markers to denote different types of events but I can't find any information anywhere as to how to implement custom MapQuest markers in Android. I am writing in Java and using an Android MapFragment.

```
private void addMarker(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(new LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194));
        markerOptions.title("San Francisco");
        markerOptions.snippet("Welcome to San Fran!");
        mapboxMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

I just can't find anywhere a color option or how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I finally found the explanation here:
https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/map-sdk/overview/annotations/